# Eigenspace of complex eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in End(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\lambda$ a complex eigenvalue of $A$. Hence an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is complex.

(If it was $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ instead: It is ($Av = \lambda v$) but
($\operatorname{Im}(Av) = 0 \land \operatorname{Im}(\lambda v) \neq 0$))

---

**My Question is the following: What is the Eigenspace $\operatorname{Eig}(\lambda)$?**

From the definition [Wikipedia Eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Formal_definition) I'd say $\operatorname{Eig}(\lambda)$ has to be a $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace. Hence $\operatorname{Eig}(\lambda) = 0$.

But how to name those $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $Av = \lambda v$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation $A \in \operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$ cannot have a (non-real) complex eigenvalue. As you note, it is impossible to have $Av = \lambda v$ when $\lambda \in \Bbb C \setminus\Bbb R$. For that matter, it is arguable that the expression $\lambda v$ cannot be interpreted in this context.

The values that are called "the complex eigenvalues of $A$" are really the eigenvalues of the [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification#Linear_transformations) of $A$, $A^{\Bbb C} \in \operatorname{End}(\Bbb C^n)$.

Comment: Thanks Ben! :) So when calculating eigenspaces for complex eigenvalues I will make sure to interpret $A \in End(\mathbb{C})$